# PUT request in Tasty PIE to update using non PK value

Tags: tastypie

I am using Tasty Pie to create Services. I have applied filtering so that it searches based on non PK value:
 My api.py file :

```
class TestResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = ack_dadc.objects.all()
    authorization = Authorization()
    filtering = {
        'DistributorUID': ['exact'],

    }
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
```

My question is:
  Can I do a PUT request based on http:localhost/api/v1/test/?DistributorUID=steve
I have googled a lot but no luck I just want to update the database based on non PK value.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find an example of how to achieve this using normal URL arguments in the Tastypie Cookbook: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-non-pk-data-for-your-urls

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this : filters are only applied on *GET* requests.

So if you want to achieve this you have to do it with 2 requests :

```
GET http:localhost/api/v1/test/?DistributorUID=steve
```

to get the ID of the resource and then

```
PUT http:localhost/api/v1/test/ID
```

to update it based on its ID.

Comment: Can I override the def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs): method of Resource.py?